# Uncertainty in distance from uncertainty in coordinates

Tags: error-propagation

I know this is basic, but I've managed to get myself confused.  So, I have an object at location $(x,y,z)$ with uncertainty in the location of $(\delta x, \delta y, \delta z)$.  What is the uncertainty in the distance from the origin to the object?  I am getting

$\displaystyle \frac{x\delta x+y\delta y+z\delta z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

Correct?  This seems like a very natural example for uncertainty analysis, but I couldn't find it anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: You got the correct result.

Comment: @witrup Thanks.